# How to generate date range for random data on bash

Tags: bash, date, datetime

I need to generate strings with all days in a year

ex:

```
MIN_DATE=01.01.2012

MAX_DATE=31.12.2012

for date in {1...366..1}
 do
 echo ...
done
```

Answer (score 12):

```
for d in {0..365}; do date -d "2012-01-01 + $d days" +'%d.%m.%Y'; done
```

Comment: how to do this automatically
with leak years?

Comment: @DmitryDubovitsky What do you mean? `29.02.2012` is present in the output.

Comment: Want to output it automatically, 
for example For 2011 year last record would be 2012-01-01


something that:

`days_in_year=date "2012-12-31" +"%j";

 for d in in ...`

Comment: @DmitryDubovitsky Ah, I get it now. Well, I'd just do: `for d in {0..365}; do date -d "$year-01-01 + $d days" +'%d.%m.%Y'; done | grep $year`. That'll work whether `year` is 2011 or 2012.

Comment: This is not working in OS X since it uses a different version of `date`.

Answer (score 2):

Not a pure bash solution, but my [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils) can help:

```
dseq 01.01.2012 31.12.2012 -f %d.%m.%Y -i %d.%m.%Y
=>
  01.01.2012
  02.01.2012
  ...
  31.12.2012
```

Output format can be configured with `-f` and input format with `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

Using an ISO 8601 date format (year-month-day), you can compare dates lexicographically. It's a little messier than I'd like, since `bash` doesn't have a "<=" operator for strings.

```
year=2011
d="$year-01-01"
last="$(($year+1))-01-01"
while [[ $d < $last ]]; do
    echo $d
    d=$(date +%F --date "$d + 1 day")
done
```

Comment: Comparing years lexicographically is a bad idea if your years can have a different number of digits. For example `d="999-01-01"; last="1000-01-01"` will produce no output.

Comment: ISO-8601 requires at least 4 digits for the year (although the problem will arise if you are trying to avoid a Y10k problem).